# Sliderjs and React desired behavior issues

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, translate

I am fairly new to JS and so I try to do as much as I can before asking for help... I have been at this for days now and I cannot seem to figure out how to get the demo code  from the link below to translate to react jsx. The documentation for sliderjs react is very limited and so deciphering it is extremely difficult for me. Is there any possible way to make this work?

https://codesandbox.io/s/v81ff

This demo is from this library: https://swiperjs.com/

My code is as I will post below:

```
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
// import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import './App.css';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

function App() {

  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      navigation
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
    >
    <SwiperSlide>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={1}
        navigation
        pagination={{ clickable: true, el: '.swiper-pagination-v' }}
        direction={{ vertical: true }}
        scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}

      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </SwiperSlide>

    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
);
};



export default App;
```

Including the code below has been shown to help, but it does not show up correctly on my system and simply produces errors:

```
import "swiper/swiper.scss";
import "swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss";
import "swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss";
import "swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss";
```

```
./node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss)
Cannot find module 'sass'
Require stack:
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /home/codydyar/code/Video Platform/test/test/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

After doing an install of sass, it appeared to start working better and allow those node errors to go away, but now any window resizing makes my horizontal stretch in size to an unreal height. I could set a set height, but it removes the dynamic sizing aspect of the page I am trying to create.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: It's working fine for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-mclaren-4jjxi. I renamed App to MySwiper and put it into the codesandbox app to get it on the page. Otherwise the code should be the same. What's not working for you?

Comment: Your link does not work, but I was trying to convert it to a js file with react. I know it isnt necessary and works perfectly fine as HTML, but I still would like to get it in the new format. I am trying to steer clear of html based code as I learn something new, if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish saving changes. Try it again.

Comment: https://ibb.co/M8sFVL9 I get this when I use the code you recommend and I think that's part of what's causing the headache...

Comment: Please add the errors you're getting to the body of your question.

Comment: Not sure if it notifies you upon edit, but I have done so. I appear to not have something installed but I have no idea what it is and I searched for awhile but couldnt figure out the issue.

Comment: It's sass. You need to run `npm install sass`.

Comment: Did that 3 times earlier and those errors never went away... but now of course they do.. So I have that and it looks as yours did, but now the problem of an infinite vertical scroll and no. Is there a mistake in what i translated that would do that?

Comment: you have to install sass globally `npm install -g sass` and also run command `npm i -g node-sass`

Comment: Please be specific about what is working or not working for you.  Describe the exact steps you take (so that others can recognize or reproduce the problem), and then be clear about what your expected results vs actual results were, including any error text verbatim.

Comment: Still super new to this whole stack overflow thing... apologies... i have now put the exact problem with images into the body of the problem. All i have done is take the css they use in the demo and apply it to my page. From there everything but the resizing works flawlessly.